# Use of Cocoa in C++ like in Delphi

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, delphi, cocoa

There is a pattern in Delphi to work with Cocoa classes. A blog about this pattern is here:

[Using OS X APIs directly from Delphi](http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/using_os_x_apis_directly_from_delphi)

I wonder, how it works and whether it can be done with xcode in C++ too.

As example I take the function "InternalGetMACOSPath" from System.IOUtils.pas. I put excerpts of the involved code at the end of this post. The line of code that I am interested in is:

```
  nsFile := TNSFileManager.Wrap(TNSFileManager.OCClass.defaultManager);
```

In essence the following would be an equivalent in C++:

```
NSFileManagerClass* pFManagerClass;
NSFileManager* pFManager;


// GetOCClass
void* cls = objc_getClass("NSFileManager");
pFManagerClass = Import(cls);

// Wrap
pFManager = Import(pFManagerClass->defaultManager());
```

I like to know whether the dummy function "Import" can be defined by use of Objective-C Runtime functions. I guess that Delphi has to use the Objective-C Runtime functions in the end too. From where else could it have the informations for the vtables?

### Code snippets:

```
NSFileManager = interface(NSObject)
  ['{9736DF94-95E9-4111-8C94-82D5EFF52A81}']
  function URLForDirectory(directory: NSSearchPathDirectory; inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask; appropriateForURL: NSURL; create: Boolean; error: PPointer): NSURL; cdecl;
...

NSFileManagerClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
  ['{E666ADEB-9DBE-4BF0-BEE0-5912CF9F5AB4}']
  {class} function defaultManager: Pointer; cdecl;
end;

TOCImport = class(TRawVirtualClass, ILocalObject)
TOCGenericImport<C: IObjectiveCClass; T: IObjectiveCInstance> = class(TOCImport)
TNSFileManager = class(TOCGenericImport<NSFileManagerClass, NSFileManager>)  end;


class function TOCGenericImport<C,T>.GetOCClass: C;
var
  ClassImport: TOCImport;
  ClsID: Pointer;
  ITypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
  CTypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  ITypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  CTypeInfo := TypeInfo(C);
  ClsID := objc_getClass(MarshaledAString(ShortStrToUTF8String(@ITypeInfo^.Name)));

  FClassVTable := TOCVTable.Create(CTypeInfo, False);
  ClassImport := TOCImport.Create(ClsId, nil, FClassVTable);
  ClassImport.QueryInterface(GetTypeData(CTypeInfo)^.Guid, FOCClass);
  Result := FOCCLass;
end;


class function TOCGenericImport<C,T>.Wrap(P: Pointer): T;
var
  ObjID: Pointer;
  Obj: TOCImport;
  ITypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  ITypeInfo := TypeInfo(T);
  Obj := TOCImport.Create(P, nil, GetInstanceVTable);
  Obj.QueryInterface(GetTypeData(ITypeInfo)^.Guid, Result);
end;



class function TPath.InternalGetMACOSPath(const SearchedPath: NSSearchPathDirectory; const SearchMask: NSSearchPathDomainMask): string;
var
  nsFile: NSFileManager;
  URL: NSURL;
begin
  nsFile := TNSFileManager.Wrap(TNSFileManager.OCClass.defaultManager);
  URL := nsFile.URLForDirectory(SearchedPath, SearchMask, nil, true, nil);
```